# access a variable with values from a string varriable

Tags: java

```
String a="jTextField1";
```

instead of writing jTextField1.setText("foo")
how can i use the value saved in 'a' to setText() in that text field?
Is it possible??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should have a map, or just an array.

Comment: You can't do that for actual variable names, but you can use maps (see [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html))... and for fields, you could *theoretically* use reflection (`getClass().getDeclaredField(a).get(this)`), but that would be ugly, slow, and just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Assign a name to your text fields and put them in a Map.

```
Map<String, JTextField> textFieldsByName = new HashMap<>();
textFieldsByName.put("jTextField1", someTextField);
...
String textFieldName = ...;
textFieldsByName.get(textFieldName).setText("foo");
```